# FusedLocationProviderClient With Service Android Kotlin

Tags: android, geolocation, kotlin

I am using Fused Api for location update. I am using Fused Api with Activity is working fine. But when i use it within service class its showing  [This is my Service class code . Where error occurring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zvjv.png)

Comment: Please post the code as text instead of an image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Class `Task` (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) have three overloads of method `addOnCompleteListener`:

- `addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener<TResult> listener)`
- `addOnCompleteListener(Activity activity, OnCompleteListener<TResult> listener)`
- `addOnCompleteListener(Executor executor, OnCompleteListener<TResult> listener)`

Your `Service` is neither `Activity`, nor `Executor`. So the two latter overloads are not applicable for you. Just drop the first parameter and use it like that:

`mFusedLocationClient!!.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener { task -> 
   //do something
}`